# What is the purpose of the Google search parameter "gbv"?

Tags: search, parameters

I wonder what the purpose of the "gbv" parameter is. Has any one got an idea?

Comment: I see the URL cycle between different values for "gbv=" as I get redirected. I wonder why...

Answer (score 3):

The gbv parameter is to control the presence of javascript on the page, 1=no javascript, 2=javascript.

Comment: How can this be? Both values show the results page with javascript.

Comment: @xampper no, it does have an impact. it removes javascript enabled features, such as, for example the "Search Tools" dropdown widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means Google Basic Variant. 1 = Basic Variant. 2 = Regular 
    Variant.

Try the following links with it in.

```
google.com/webhp?hl=en&gbv=1
google.com/imghp?hl=en&gbv=1
google.com/vidhp?hl=en&gbv=1
google.com/shopping?hl=en&gbv=1
```

For some reason, google disables it if you search, meaning you have to later enable it again. To bring back the regular interface, replace 1 with 2.